# What's the word for "doing something because you have to?"

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

It's part of the concept of simple living where you do something because you must or else you/others may die. Like, you build the house in the woods because you have to, there's nothing but trees. You hunt the bear because you HAVE to, to eat. Soldiers will push themselves further because they HAVE to in order to survive. You do what it takes to land the plane because you HAVE to - nobody else can do it, and you must get down or else you'll run out fuel and crash. So what do you call that simple "do what it takes" attitude?

Comment: You've explained the concept you want, but not how you want it to feature in a sentence. Are you after a noun, verb, adjective or something else? Please provide a sample sentence using X or ____ in the place of the word you're requesting.

Answer (score 3):

In an **obligation**, one has no choice. You are **obliged** to do something by external force or circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for words meaning HAVE to:

**[necessary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/necessary?utm_campaign=sd&utm_medium=serp&utm_source=jsonld)** (or [requisite](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/requisite))

> absolutely needed

[**inevitable**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inevitable)

> incapable of being avoided or evaded

[**essential**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/essential)

> of the utmost importance

see also [inescapable](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inescapable) and [imperative](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/imperative)

The *attitude* of doing what you have to could be

**[survivalism](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/survivalism)**

> an attitude, policy, or practice based on the primacy of survival as a value

*Doing* something because you have to:

**[endure](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/endure)**

> 1 to undergo especially without giving in
>
> 2 to remain firm under suffering or misfortune without yielding

**[subsist](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subsist)**

> to have or acquire the necessities of life

Comment: Do something out of necessity...

Answer (score 2):

Necessity

1. a. The condition or quality of being necessary.
   b. Something necessary: The necessities of life include food, clothing, and shelter.

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Necessity

Answer (score 1):

**Imperative **  ?
 1. absolutely necessary or required: It is imperative that we leave.
http://www.thefreedictionary.com/imperative

Answer (score 1):

The term **self-sufficiency** applies to many of the examples provided in the question.

- build the house in the woods because you have to, there's nothing but trees.
- You hunt the bear because you HAVE to, to eat.
- Soldiers will push themselves further because they HAVE to in order to survive.

> **[Self-sufficient](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/self-sufficient)**: Able to supply one's own or its own needs without external assistance

In the example cases mentioned, the person in question is not able to rely on external assistance to solve a problem, and must do what is necessary to survive.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-sufficiency) provides a more detailed description that incorporates "*simple living*," as mentioned in the question:

> Self-sufficiency is a type of sustainable living in which nothing is consumed other than what is produced by the self-sufficient individuals. Examples of attempts at self-sufficiency in North America include simple living, homesteading, off-the-grid, survivalism, DIY ethic and the back-to-the-land movement.